# How to skip end few records when loading external table in Amazon Redshift Spectrum?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

My file has text at the end.

While creating external table I'm loading file from S3 and which I don't want to load in my table.

How to skip that text from the end?

Comment: You cannot do that - you need to find another way. Please update your question with the copy command you are using and an example of the s3 data

Comment: Please also describe your ETL process, ie how do the files get to s3, how many are there, how often you copy to redshift - etc

Comment: Hi Rishant, are you actually loading (using COPY) the data into Redshift, or are you using files stored on S3 with Spectrum (external tables) to represent the data? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Actually i'm not using copy command, i'm using the files which are stored in S3 with spectrum to represent data

Answer (score -1):

You cannot explicitly skip rows at the end but you can allow a certain number of errors with the MAXERROR parameter. Should be able to set that to (`number of lines to skip` * `number of files to be loaded`).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror

Comment: Joe, can't you have >1 error per row? Not ideal solution for large amounts of data - or when you need to be sure on data accuracy - max value = 1,000,000

Comment: This will potentially be dangerous in a way that other than OP's intention to skip last n rows, it could introduce more data problems allowing errors to pass.

Comment: this is the solution while using copy command but i'm not using copy command